# C# Active Directory PrincipalContext / UserPrincipal.IsMemberOf error

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryservices

So I have a question I'm honestly not quite sure how to ask. Essentially I have a bit of code that works fantastically on my local machine when I run it. Once I publish it to our development web server, it fails. I'm not sure if it's an IIS setup issue, web.config issue or a coding issue.

Here's the snippet of code

```
    bool isMember = false;

    PrincipalContext ADDomain = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
    UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ADDomain, userID);

    if (user.IsMemberOf(ADDomain, IdentityType.Name, groupName.Trim()))
    {
        isMember = true;
    }

    return isMember;
```

Where I pass in a user name and a group and it tells me if that user’s a member in that group. No problem. Works great on my machine. I went to publish that code to the webserver and it fails when it hits the line

```
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ADDomain, userID);
```

it throws this error:

> [DirectoryServicesCOMException (0x80072020): An operations error occurred.]
>   System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail) +788
>   System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind() +44
>   System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_AdsObject() +42
>   System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection.PopulateList() +29
>   System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection..ctor(DirectoryEntry
>   entry, String propertyName) +63
>   System.DirectoryServices.PropertyCollection.get_Item(String propertyName) +163
>       System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.DoLDAPDirectoryInitNoContainer()
>   +521217
>   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.DoDomainInit()
>   +51
>   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.Initialize()
>   +141
>   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.get_QueryCtx()
>   +42
>         System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal.FindByIdentityWithTypeHelper(PrincipalContext
>   context, Type principalType, Nullable`1 identityType, String
>   identityValue, DateTime refDate) +29
>   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(PrincipalContext
>   context, String identityValue) +95
>   Cosmic.Web.Login.btnSubmit_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\cosmic\Cosmic.Web\Login.aspx.cs:79
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +154
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3691

Any ideas where this could be failing?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

My first guess would be: that user account you're running this code under doesn't have the necessary permissions to query Active Directory.

To fix this, basically you need to change your constructor from this:

```
PrincipalContext ADDomain = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
```

*(establishes a connection to AD with the current, default credentials this code is running under)*

to this:

```
PrincipalContext ADDomain = 
   new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "DOMAIN", useraccount, password);
```

and provide a username and password for a user account that you know has sufficient privileges to query Active Directory.

Comment: You know what, that's what it was. The webserver doesn't have the right credentials to hit Active Directory. Put some credentials in there and it works quite a bit better. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you've got several seconds to spare waiting for your data form a large AD, then go ahead and use PrincipalContext but if you want your response in milliseconds, use DirectoryEntry, DirectorySearcher and .PropertiesToLoad.

Here's an example

https://stackoverflow.com/a/65986796/5248400