# Search a user login id by first name and last name

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I found [How can I get a list of users from active directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5162897/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-users-from-active-directory)

It is helpful when I only have a few users, but I have so many users in AD, so when I run my query

```
if ((String)(entry.Properties["sn"].Value) == "lname"
     && (String)(entry.Properties["givenName"].Value) == "fname")
{
    return entry.Properties["samAccountName"].Value.ToString();
}
```

it took too long to finish.

What can I do to search one particular user logon id by first name and last name?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since you're on .NET 4, you should check out the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace. Read all about it here:

- [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)
- [MSDN docs on System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx)

Basically, you can define a domain context and easily find users and/or groups in AD:

```
// set up domain context
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

// find a user - by e.g. his "samAccountName", or the Windows user name or something
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "SomeUserName");

if(user != null)
{
   // do something here....     
   string samAccountName = user.SamAccountName;
}
```

If you cannot find a user specified by a user name, you can also use the new search functionality:

```
// define a "query-by-example" principal - here, we search for a UserPrincipal 
// and with the first name (GivenName) and a last name (Surname) 
UserPrincipal qbeUser = new UserPrincipal(ctx);
qbeUser.GivenName = firstName;
qbeUser.Surname = lastName;

// create your principal searcher passing in the QBE principal    
PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeUser);

// find all matches
foreach(var found in srch.FindAll())
{
    // do whatever here - "found" is of type "Principal" - it could be user, group, computer.....          
}
```

The new S.DS.AM makes it really easy to play around with users and groups in AD! And just finding a single user should be relatively quick, too.

Comment: @marc_s this was exactly what I was looking for, perfect, thanks... however, I did find out the hard way that if any field you request from the user for searching is not needed, skip the corresponding property in the `UserPrincipal`. I originally was pushing `string.empty` and then even `null` and was having **no** results returned. However, as soon as I added an `if` statement and ignored that item in the `UserPrincipal`, I finally had results returned (_ie: skipped **GivenName** when the **FirstName** was not populated, instead of setting to default_).

Answer (score 4):

You should be using the AD server to do the filtering. Do this by supplying an LDAP syntax filter. Also, specify only the properties you need using the `propertiesToLoad` argument of `FindAll`:

```
    public static SearchResultCollection FindByName(
        string domain, string firstName, string lastName, string[] properties) {
        var rootEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + domain);
        var filter = string.Format("(&(sn={0})(givenName={1}))", lastName, firstName);
        var searcher = new DirectorySearcher(rootEntry, filter, properties);
        return searcher.FindAll();
    }

    // Using the method:
    var result = FindByName("mydomain", "Robert", "Smith", new[] { "samAccountName" })[0];
    string uName = (string)result.Properties["samAccountName"][0];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the [QueryFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principalsearcher.queryfilter.aspx) property on `searcher`, and then call `searcher.FindOne()` instead of `searcher.FindAll()`.  The query filter can be set to a [UserPrincipal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.userprincipal.aspx) object where you set the fields that you want to search on.

Microsoft has a good example of this at the [Query By Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384378.aspx) page though their example expects to find several objects matching the given criteria.

A particularly literal adaptation of the linked question to your requirement would be

```
using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "mydomain.com"))
{
    using (var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(new UserPrincipal(context) { GivenName = "fname", Surname = "lname" }))
    {
            foreach (var result in searcher.FindAll())
            {
                DirectoryEntry de = result.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;
                return de.Properties["samAccountName"].Value.ToString();
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `entry` is part of an `IEnumerable` collection, you could do something like:

```
var entries = {do your population of the collection here}

var entry = entries.Where(e=>e.Properties["sn"].Value.ToString() == "lname"
    && e=>.Properties["givenName"].Value.ToString() == "fname")
    .FirstOrDefault();
```