# How do i get a list of users in active directory using .NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory

I want to get a list of users in active directory. How would i achieve this in asp.net?

What objects and functions are invloved. Has anyone got any sample code?

Comment: Did you try something?

Comment: Did you even search for it? Google! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5162897/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-users-from-active-directory

Comment: I had a quick look on google but there seems to be a lot of different approaches.  I was wondering if there was a common approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have any sample code right now, but I think using an external text file would do.

You can store your data in a normal .txt file or XML file. I usually use XML file for storing data in the project's directory.

Tutorials for reading and writing XML files are all over the internet for C#. Just search on Google!

Good Luck!

Comment: How does this in any way answer the question asked, or even the question that it may be trying to address? Basically this selected answer is "Google something irrelevant"