# Loop LDAP memberOf as return to show all for single user

Tags: c#

Pretty new to using LDAP, and C# in general, and I did more than a few searches, but most of my attempted fixes have lead nowhere.

I am pulling information from the LDAP. Everything works, except I can only pull the memberOf information if I am explicit in which array number I want. Attempts to use a `foreach`, or a `for` statement have lead nowhere. I know I am probably missing something simple, but I figured I should just ask.

```
public static String FindOther(String userAccount)
{
   DirectoryEntry entry = GetDirectoryEntry();
   DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
   try
   {
      search.Filter = "(SAMAccountName=" + account + ")";
      search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedName"); 
      search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("displayName"); 
      search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail"); 
      search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("CN");
      search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("Title");
      search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sn");
      search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("givenname");
      search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("telephoneNumber");
      search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("memberOf"); 
      SearchResult result = search.FindOne();

      if (result != null)
      {
         return
            "Results for " + userAccount + "\n" +
            " DistinguishedName..: " + result.Properties["distinguishedName"][0].ToString() + "\n" +
            " Displayname........: " + result.Properties["displayname"][0].ToString() + "\n" +
            " eMail..............: " + result.Properties["mail"][0].ToString() + "\n" +
            " Common Name........: " + result.Properties["CN"][0].ToString() + "\n" +
            " Title..............: " + result.Properties["Title"][0].ToString() + "\n" +
            " Last Name..........: " + result.Properties["sn"][0].ToString() + "\n" +
            " First Name.........: " + result.Properties["givenname"][0].ToString() + "\n" +
            " Telephone..........: " + result.Properties["telephoneNumber"][0].ToString() + "\n" +                                    
            " Member Of..........: " + result.Properties["memberOf"][0].ToString() + "\n" +  
            " Member Of..........: " + result.Properties["memberOf"][1].ToString() + "\n" +  
            "End Transmission" + "\n";
         }
         else
         {
            return "Object not found... User ID: " + account;
         }
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
         return "Big Ol Error: " + ex.Message + " User ID: " + account;
      }
   }
```

Thank you all for any help you could provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enumerate through an PropertyCollection this way:

```
   string Ret = string.Empty;
   ...
   foreach(object memberOf in result.Properties["memberOf"])
   {
      Ret += " Member Of..........: " + memberOf.ToString() + "\n";
   }
```

Comment: This worked perfectly once I was smart enough to put it after the SearchResult, before the if(result!=null), and add the +Ret in the return. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to give a slight disclaimer here, mostly because I've never coded to *Active Directory* or the *Lightweight Directory Access Protocol*.  Some of the things that I do know, is a `DirectoryEntry` usage recommends:

> Use GetDirectoryEntry when you want to look at the live entry instead
>   of the entry that was returned through DirectorySearcher, or when you
>   want to invoke a method on the object that was returned.

This particular method will return the information directly from *Active Directory*.  Where `DirectorySearcher` will only generate through what is currently available in the collection. I mention this, because without the collection being filled it won't generate much.

[I'm not sure what type of application your building, but Microsoft has an entire area within Microsoft Developer Network that mentions how to integrate several LDAP / AD features into an application.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649227.aspx)

I'm not sure of your entire goal, but I believe this is what you are seeking.  If not let me know and I'll modify the code.

static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string groupName = "Domain Users";
        string domainName = "";

```
    PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domainName);
    GroupPrincipal grp = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.SamAccountName, groupName);

    if (grp != null)
    {
         foreach (Principal p in grp.GetMembers(false))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(p.SamAccountName + " - " + p.DisplayName);
            }


        grp.Dispose();
        ctx.Dispose();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nWe did not find that group in that domain, perhaps the group resides in a different domain?");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

This code was actually from a book, it was used to accomplish such a goal.  But as I stated up top, I've never physically done such a task- I'm just hoping to point you in the proper direction.

[Another question similar to yours can be found here, which contains good reference and answers your question I believe.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5162897/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-users-from-active-directory)

Comment: This is fantastic, and will help me with other parts of the code that I need, but wasn't quite what I was after. However, the other answer provided worked perfectly. Thank you, though, for the resources you included!!

Comment: Not a problem, just happy that helped.