# How to get the computer name of a person

Tags: c#, active-directory

Is it possible to get the computer name for a person that is found through Active Directory?

I am currently getting the person via `DirectorySearcher` object, and from there can get the user's SID, but i don't know where to look next in order to find the actual computer name that is assigned to that SID or person?

Or maybe there is an easier way to get this information from Active Directory?

Comment: Computers are not assigned to users as far as I know.

Comment: depending on your organization, they actually are. At least on the business side... for example, i, Maxovrdr, have been assigned 2 computers, NHQ-12345 and NHQ-12346 ... so basically there's no way to get that information out of ADS directly?

Comment: Where does that assignment exist, i.e. if I were looking at it in AD Users & Computers?

Comment: that's what i'm trying to figure out! ;) or if it does at all...

Comment: That's what I meant by my comment.  AD does not store an association between users and computers.

Comment: then please post as answer since you actually gave the answer in a comment before anyone else. I will accept it, and query my local Network Admin folks to find out how i can get to that information instead of through ADS.

Comment: Go ahead and accept the other answer if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no association of computers to users in default AD - so there is no way to get such information.

You may find last/currently logged on set of machines for a user (also I don't think this is available in AD, see [How to find what user last logged onto a given computer through Active Directory in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19842212/how-to-find-what-user-last-logged-onto-a-given-computer-through-active-directory) for some starting points) or maybe you add custom information that gives that association in AD ([Retrieving custom Active Directory properties of users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8927309/retrieving-custom-active-directory-properties-of-users)).