# How do I get lastLogon from Active Directory with C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, active-directory

I'm trying to get the LastLogon from a user in the active directory but I have this code

```
 lblUsernameDisplay.Text = "LastLogon : " + (DateTime.FromFileTime((long)rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["lastLogon"][0])).ToString();
```

And I got an error, I also tried without long cast, without ToString() and with `.Value.ToString() instead of [0]`

UPDATE:

I got this error: `Specified cast is not valid.`

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: @MarkC. Long cast isn't allowed here, and if I do like this --´rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["lastLogon"][0].ToString(); returns me a´System.___Com....

Comment: You sure this SO question wouldn't help? It covers this question and how to handle with multiple domain controllers.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19454162/getting-last-logon-time-on-computers-in-active-directory