# Get list of users of Active directory in the server

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, active-directory

i want to have a list of all users in the active directory in the server and use it in my c# application

```
string DomainPath = "LDAP://192.168.1.250/Domain";
DirectoryEntry searchRoot = new DirectoryEntry(DomainPath,"user","password");
```

this code don't work

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5162897/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-users-from-active-directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following code

```
DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(searchRoot);
search.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person))";
```

In `DirectorySearcher`, create a *DirectorySearcher object* which **searches** for all users in a domain. `search.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person))"` *filters* the search.

Comment: Just a small addition: this page contains some example of querying ldap. http://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gapps/docs/admin/en/gads/admin/ldap.5.4.html

Comment: i think i have a problem in the code that i post (DomainPath )