# How can I get all Active Directory Users username and display name

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, active-directory

I have an Intranet application using ASP.Net MVC 5

I need to query all Active directory users username

I searched the net I found 2 useful post:
    1- [How can I get a list of users from active directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5162897/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-users-from-active-directory)

2- http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/599697/Get-list-of-Active-Directory-users-in-Csharp

When I query I can get the Name property but I can't get the active directory usernames

any solutions that I can get all Active directory users username?

bellow is my code:

```
        List<TempUsers> MyTempUser = new List<TempUsers>();

        var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "MyDomain.com");
        var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(new UserPrincipal(context));

        foreach (var result in searcher.FindAll())
        {
            DirectoryEntry de = result.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;
            MyTempUser.Add(new TempUsers { UserName = de.Properties["Name"].Value.ToString() });


        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it this way it worked great:

1- Add reference to Active Directory services DLL

2- Add using in your controller:

```
 using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
```

than I created a function to store All Active directory users in database table
 bellow is the code hope help someone needs it.

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {


        List<MyADUsers> TheAllADUsers = new List<MyADUsers>();

        var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "MyDoman.org");
        var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(new UserPrincipal(context));

        foreach (var result in searcher.FindAll())
        {

            TheAllADUsers.Add(new MyADUsers { ADUserName = result.SamAccountName, AD_IsMemberOf = result.UserPrincipalName, FullName = result.Name });

        }

        db.MyADUsersContext.AddRange(TheAllADUsers);
        db.SaveChanges();


        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The property name you're looking for is `sAMAccountName`.
[Here's](http://www.kouti.com/tables/userattributes.htm) a list of the available attributes.