# Returning System.Object[] from Active Directory SQL Query

Tags: sql, ssis, active-directory

I am working on creating a SSIS package that needs to access Active Directory.  I have created an ADO.NET connection and wrote a select LDAP query to pull back the records (see below).  I am able to retrieve the data successfully, but one of the Active Directory attributes is returning System.Object[] instead of the department number I desire.  Is there a way to successfully convert the System.Object into the real data using the query?  Thanks in advance.

Example query:

```
SELECT department, departmentnumber, sAMAccountName
FROM 'LDAP://example.com' WHERE objectClass='User'
```

Results:

```
|department |departmentnumber   |sAMAccountName|
|Hollywood  |System.Object[]    |ceastwood     |
```

*UPDATE: After my research I will add that I don't believe this LDAP SQL query is possible to use if it's returning System.Object.  I found many great examples of using a script task to perform a similar operation like this one [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5162897/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-users-from-active-dir)*

*I created a console application and built it up to insert my Active Directory data right into SQL.  I would recommend following along to the articles found on Stack Over Flow.  They helped me a great deal to accomplish this task, even though it wasn't the way I wanted.*

Comment: If you use something like [SysInternals ADExplorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/adexplorer), what does it show for the Syntax of `departmentnumber`?

Comment: Using the above tool (thanks for that), while navigating to the CN=departmentNumber, it has several attributes all with different Syntax.  Which attribute should I be looking for?

The attributeSyntax Attribute Syntax = DirectoryString

Comment: For what it's worth.. inside the Data Flow ADO NET Source, when I preview the query, it show the System.object at that level, so that rules out the data flow destination not causing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Before reading this further, please ensure that the object[] can be parsed as string[].

I'll share a sample way of how I'm converting the output of `memberOf` attribute from object[] to string[] for readability purpose in our environment:

```
object[] membership = user.Properties["MemberOf"].Value as object[];
                    if (membership != null)
                    {
                        string[] roles = Array.ConvertAll<object, string>(membership, convertObjectToString);
                        if (roles != null)
                        {
                            foreach (string role in roles)
                                LogInformation.log("Role " + role);
                        }
                        else
                            LogInformation.log("Member Of not found!");
                    }
```

Whereas, convertObjectToString() is a static method as declared below:

```
private static string convertObjectToString(object obj)
    {
        return (obj == null) ? string.Empty : obj.ToString(); 
    }
```

Comment: I was trying to perform this using a sql query.  Is the only way to successfully do this by creating a script task?

Comment: @Clint - yes, it is possible to achieve what you want. Search on the web for "Calling managed code from SQL-Server", e.g., https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/introduction-to-sql-server-clr-integration ; remember - it'd be equivalent to fight a war using a needle!

Comment: Haha, yes I agree.  I have began writing some C# to perform this in a script task, but it bothers me that I can't get this to work in a SQL query.  Thanks for the link.

Comment: @Clint - You may like to accept the answer as well, if it helped you. See how to accept an answer -> https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work