# Show AD User's On SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have a requirement to fetch all active directory users data to be added in sharepoint list and show on different pages.

How we can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

see below to get C# code to do that. Depending upon the sharepoint api (Server object model/CSOM/JSOM) you are using, you would have to take the results from this code to your pages.

[How can I get a list of users from active directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5162897/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-users-from-active-directory)